# Android Chrome Background Image Pixelated

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I'm having a strange issue in Chrome on Android.

I have a repeated pattern as a background, it's in a nice resolution, it should display absolutely crystal clear on smaller screens with a high pixel density, but it isn't!

It's gone totally potato.

[evolved dev site](http://evolved.jamrockdesign.uk)

From what I've read this is a known issue, but the only information I could find was regarding svg's.

Is there a work around for this?!

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the background in Android?

Comment: Seems like this might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598637/background-attachment-fixed-interfering-with-background-size . I remember reading an article recently about the problems they had getting fixed attachment working correctly with the GPU acceleration in android chrome. Apparently it's still having issues.